# error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'WTTMetadataDefinition' in WTTLogger.h Microsoft header file

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, static-libraries, header-files

I'm using the WTTLogger (downloaded from WLK- windows logo kit) in my c++ application. I don't get any compilation/linker errors with an older version of wtt library WTTLog.DLL/lib and WTTlogger.h header file.

But with a latest version of the header file and library , I'm getting the following error **in the header file**

**This is a Microsoft given header file and I'm not able to understand this error in the microsoft given header file. Any inputs would be greatly appreciated**.
::

```
error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'WTTMetadataDefinition'
error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'WTTMetadataReference'
error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'WTTMetadataDefinition'
error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'WTTMetadataReference'
```

Comment: Have you updated your project dependencies to match the newer version of the library?

Comment: yes, of course I have updated the project dependencies for header file, lib file and DLL.

Comment: You can use the [/showIncludes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hdkef6tk.aspx) compiler switch to display the included header files. This allows you to see **where** the header files are included from. If you are using precompiled headers make sure to rebuild the solution after switching to another version of a library.

Comment: @IInspectable :: Thanks a ton. :) :) By using /showIncludes option I could figure out that the include had further dependencies and I had to replace even the header files on which this particular header file was dependent. It solved my problem.